# SAPUI5 file upload

Tags: file-upload, sapui5

I am creating an SAPUI5 app that needs to upload attachments. I still am very new use SAPUi5. I want to save the uploaded file to the DB. Could I use the Document service? If so please provide me with docs or tutorials to do so.

Answer (score 2):

I have done that in one off my SAPUI5 apps, for the uploading function [check out my gist.](https://gist.github.com/elsheikh21/32a3d4d642be35199b6f5b985f841578)

Or check [this for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399121/how-to-upload-files-in-sapui5/47728848#47728848)

```
onUpload: function(e) {
  var fU = this.getView().byId("idfileUploader");
  var domRef = fU.getFocusDomRef();
  var file = domRef.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(oEvent) {
    var strCSV = oEvent.target.result;
    var arrCSV = strCSV.match(/[\w .]+(?=,?)/g);
    var noOfCols = 6;
    var headerRow = arrCSV.splice(0, noOfCols);
    var data = [];
    while (arrCSV.length > 0) {
      var obj = {};
      var row = arrCSV.splice(0, noOfCols);
      for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        obj[headerRow[i]] = row[i].trim();
      }
      data.push(obj);
    }
  };
  reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18633279)

Comment: Okay thank you for this review, I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective of whether you use DB or [Document Service](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/help/frameset.htm?e60b7e45bb57101487a881c7c5487778.html), with respect to SAPUI5,
you can use `sap.ui.unified.FileUploader`. Read more [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/entity/sap.ui.unified.FileUploader/samples)

Sample XML code would be:

```
<sap.ui.unified:FileUploader
    id="fileUploader"
    width="100%"
    uploadUrl=""
    placeholder="Add attachment"
    uploadOnChange="false"
    uploadComplete="handleUploadComplete"
    change="handleValueChange"
    typeMissmatch="handleTypeMissmatch"
    style="Emphasized"
    useMultipart="false" >
</sap.ui.unified:FileUploader>
```

While uploading make sure, you add slug and x-csrf-token to the headerparameters.

Example:

```
 var oFileUploader = _this.byId("fileUploader");
 oFileUploader.addHeaderParameter(new sap.ui.unified.FileUploaderParameter({
                    name: "slug",
                    value: oFileUploader.getValue()
                }));
 oFileUploader.addHeaderParameter(new sap.ui.unified.FileUploaderParameter({
                    name: "x-csrf-token",
                    value: _this.oDataModel.getSecurityToken()
                }));
 oFileUploader.upload();
```

And if you are using ABAP Netweaver gateway stack, you need to implement CREATE_STREAM method in DPC_EXT classes. Also need to make sure that pareticular EventType with "media" supported in Gateway model.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, when this upload occurs where does it get saved? Also what is the need for the slug and x-csrf-token?

Comment: slug for file name, and x-csrf-token for POST request

Answer (score -1):

```
uploadFile:function{
    var that = this;
    var count = 0;
    var o = "<URI>";
    var h = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(o, true);
    var d = "";
    h.setSizeLimit(5000);
    h.forceNoCache(true);
    var b = ({
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-CSRF-Token": "Fetch",
    });
    OData.request({
        requestUri: o,
        method: "GET",
        headers: b
    }, function (e, j) {
        d = j.headers["x-csrf-token"];
        that.csrfToken = d;
        that.getModel("oAppData").setProperty("/busyIndicators/uploadFile", true);
        for (var l = 0; l < that.fileDataAD.length; l++) {
            var i = "<URI>";
            var h = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(i, true);
            h.setSizeLimit(5000);
            h.forceNoCache(true);
            var b = ({
                "X-CSRF-Token": that.csrfToken,
                "Slug": that.fileDataAD[l].fileName + "|" + that.fileDataAD[l].fileType + "|" + "B" + "|" + reqId + "|" + 1
            });
            OData.request({
                requestUri: i,
                method: "POST",
                headers: b,
                data: that.fileDataAD[l].file
            }, function (oData, oRes) {
                count = count + 1;
                if (count === that.fileDataAD.length) {
                    that._uploadCompleteAddDependent();
                }
            }.bind(this), function (oError) { }                     
        }           
    });
 }
```

where `fileDataAD` is buffer array