# Upload Files in UI5 without using Create Stream in Gateway

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm building an UI5 application where I need to send several entities to backend at the same time (I'm using create_deep_entity method for that).

I'm using the concept of master-detail (father and children). One of these children is a set of files which need to be sent to backend at the same request as other entities (I want to send them together on create deep).

Is there a way I can use an UI5 component (file upload maybe?) to read the files and send to backend without using create stream method (it must be sent along with other entities on create deep)?

Apreciate your input on this

Comment: I would do this in two steps. First create your entities (the response of this call should contain your new unique key for the entities). Then do the upload. You can pass the unique key to the create_stream method via the header parameter `slug` and then connect your uploaded files to your created entities using the unique key.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Upload files in SAPUI5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399121/how-to-upload-files-in-sapui5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard UI5 component that can be used to upload files and send them to the backend without using the create stream method. However, you can create a custom component that will allow you to do this.

You will need to create a custom component that will read the files and send them to the backend. This will require some custom coding.

coding example:

```
var oFileUploader = new sap.ui.unified.FileUploader({
    uploadUrl: "your_backend_url",
    uploadOnChange: false,
    multiple: true
});

oFileUploader.attachChange(function(oEvent){
    var aFiles = oEvent.getParameter("files");
    for(var i=0; i<aFiles.length; i++){
        var oFile = aFiles[i];
        var oRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        oRequest.open("POST", "your_backend_url");
        var oFormData = new FormData();
        oFormData.append("file", oFile);
        oRequest.send(oFormData);
    }
});
```

Comment: Although not the perfect solution, that's the similar concept I followed. I read file base64 value and send it through the entities. With that value I can handle the files on Abap side. Thanks for the help.